# angular 4 templating without components?

Tags: angular

Is there any way to declare/use a "template" fragment in angular 2/4?
let say I have 2 components with some duplicate section in them and I don't want to make this section a @Component. is there anyway to avoid it?
let assume the following fragment :

```
<div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
    <label for="to_date">To</label>
    <datetime id="to_date" [(ngModel)]="to_date" [timepicker]="false" 
              (ngModelChange)="onToDateChanged($event)" 
              [datepicker]="to_options">
   </datetime>
</div>
```

I don't want to declare this div on each page I need a datetime picker, and I also don't want to make it a @Component.
Any suggestion/workaround/help?

Comment: Are you looking for something like a custom structural directive? ([documentation link](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#write-a-structural-directive))

Comment: No, just looking for some include directive , I know I can use bend  @Directive for my case, but i was wondering if there's something more straight forward..  like good-old-templating language with include

Comment: No, there is no `ng-include` in angular 2+.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to define a template in your parent and pass it to your children using `ngTemplateOutlet`.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

Try looking at this article for more information:

http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

One simple potential solution, close to what you want:

You can define a template in your parent component:

```
<div #myTemplate>Hello</div>
```

Then get a reference to it using a ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild('myTemplate') templateForChild;
```

You can then pass it to your child:

```
<your-component [template]='templateForChild'></your-component>
```

Then accept that as input in your component:

```
public class YourComponent {
    @Input() template: TemplateRef;
    ....
}
```